# Странное поведение уникального идентификатора во внешнем источнике данных (1С, SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, 1с

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table](
    [row_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_payments1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( 
    [row_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

На 1С создаю внешний источник данных на сервере SQL, добавляю туда таблицу `TABLE`. 1C устанавливает для поля `row_id` тип `число(10)` и для поля `_id` тип `УникальныйИдентификатор`. Выбираю данные в запросе и получаю в представлении поля `_id` совсем не то что в таблице на SQL сервере. Если для поля `_id` установить тип `Строка(36)`, то всё отлично совпадает.

Какое есть объяснение всему этому?

---

**Пример**:

- на SQL в выборке `_id` отображается как
  `2fbcab2b-c1fd-4158-bff2-36d5bff1512b`
- на 1С при `_id` с типом `УникальныйИдентификатор`
  `bff1512b-36d5-bff2-2bab-bc2ffdc15841`
- на 1С при `_id` с типом `Строка(36)`
  `2fbcab2b-c1fd-4158-bff2-36d5bff1512b`

**PS**
Если присмотреться, то можно заметить, что во втором случае идентификатор похож на первый, но с перемешанными блоками.

Comment: можно предположить, что поле получается в двоичном виде, а при интерпретации в строковое представление для вывода байты берутся в другом порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто. SQL Server работает с UUID, а 1С с GUID
Вот здесь https://infostart.ru/public/99109/ очень наглядная картинка, чем UUID отличается от GUID
Там же описаны функции UUIDtoGUID И GUIDtoUUID

Comment: это у вас откуда такая информация, что *SQL Server работает с UUID*?

Comment: в статье информация любопытна, но только с практической точки зрения - с академической точки зрения это как-то ненаучно, либо все эти стандарты взяты из шкатулки 1С, ибо [GUID имеет 32 символа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID)

Comment: Упс. Да, попутала. GUID в SQL Server конечно же.  
GUID - стандарт микрософтовского uuid.

Comment: Точнее микрософтовская реализация стандарта UUID. Что там и как там варится UUID в 1C - это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Это не другой вопрос, это именно этот вопрос, который я задал. Интересуют подробности реализации UUID в 1с

Comment: Стандарт UUID может быть реализован несколькими способами. Нужно читать стандарт. GUID - это не единственно верная реализация, но которая во многих случаях звучит как синоним UUID.  1С реализует, видимо другой вариант. Документацию по этому поводу достаточно сложно найти.  Вот здесь много интересного можно почитать http://qaru.site/questions/1762/is-there-any-difference-between-a-guid-and-a-uuid

Comment: (по ссылке про UUID, а не про 1C)

Comment: спасибо, интересует именно как реализовано это в 1с

Comment: Вас картинка по ссылке не устраивает?! Там же наглядно показана перестановка! 32 символа, потому что без 4х символов "-"  . Добавьте их и будет 36!  Там же приведены функции, как получит родной GUID и обратно.

Comment: зачем мне эти костыли? почитайте второй комментарий, я уже писал, что эта статья годна только для решения симптома проблемы, но не даёт никакого понимания - это просто костыль

Answer (score 1):

При записи уникального идентификатора в поле таблицы внешнего источника данных платформа «1С:Предприятие» выполняет перестановку данных уникального идентификатора. Таким образом, данные во внешнюю базу данных будут помещаться в измененном виде. При чтении уникального идентификатора данные переставляются обратно. Поэтому, при записи/чтении уникальный идентификатор сохраняет свое исходное значение.

Хранение значение типа УникальныйИдентификатор в памяти компьютера можно представить следующим образом (порядок байт «младший-старший»):

● значение Data1 длиной 4 байта;

● значение Data2 длиной 2 байта;

● значение Data3 длиной 2 байта;

● значение Data4 длиной 8 байта.

Запись в базу данных значения типа УникальныйИдентификатор для такого хранения будет выполняться в следующем порядке:

● целиком значение Data4;

● 1-й байт значения Data3;

● 0-й байт значения Data3;

● 1-й байт значения Data2;

● 0-й байт значения Data2;

● 3-й байт значения Data1;

● 2-й байт значения Data1;

● 1-й байт значения Data1;

● 0-й байт значения Data1.

Answer (score 1):

Давно это было

Я сделал так

```
declare  @Code binary(16) = 0xBE00005056B8004C11EAF74254FD81D0
        ,@UIC uniqueidentifier = '54fd81d0-f742-11ea-be00-005056b8004c'

--SQL => 1CGUID
select UUID =  convert(uniqueidentifier, (convert( 
binary(8),REVERSE(substring(@Code,9,8)))+substring(@Code,1,8)))

--1CGUID => SQL 
select SQLBin = substring(convert(binary(16),@UIC),9,8)+convert(binary(8),reverse(substring(convert(binary(16),@UIC),1,8)))
```

Результаты

```
UUID
------------------------------------
54FD81D0-F742-11EA-BE00-005056B8004C

(1 row affected)

SQLBin
----------------------------------
0xBE00005056B8004C11EAF74254FD81D0

(1 row affected)
```